# Styles of component imported from component library not applied during ssr

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs, styled-components, webpack-5

I have come across an issue where styles of a component, that is imported from my component library which is bundled with webpack 5, are not applied during ssr.

I have two projects.

A NextJs app with SC. Importing a component library:

- Minimal reproduction repo:
  https://github.com/tadej321/nextjs-test.git

A React component library with SC and bundled with webpack 5. Imported into my NextJs app:

- minimal reproduction repo:
  https://github.com/tadej321/component-library-test.git

The component library is added as a dependancy to the NextJs app.
Once the page is updated on the client, the styles are applied correctly, just the inital render of the page lacks the styles.

I do not know if the problem is with SC or NextJs. But if I dont bundle the component library with webpack and instead only transpile with babel using this configuration:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins":
  [
    "babel-plugin-styled-components"
  ]
}
```

then NextJs performs ssr with styles applied.

I have set up a minimal reproduction repo, so that anyone can test out this issue, below are the commands to compile the component library. Feel free to push and pull your changes to the repo I have provided.

To bundle the component library run the npm run build command and set the main in package.json to:

```
"main": "./dist/index.js"
```

To transpile with babel run the npm run transpile command and set the main in package.json to:

```
"main": "./dist/index.transpiled.js"
```

If I have not provided enough information to resolve this issue please let me know and I will add it to the post.

## Edit:

In the screenshot bellow, you can see two components. The top is defined in the next.js app and is rendered with styles. The bottom is imported from the component library and lacks styles when rendered on the server.

[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQEsp.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'initial render'?

Comment: I mean on server side render, the page that is served from the next.js server.

Comment: Is the issue that when you compile with webpack you're not transpiling correctly with the `babel-plugin-styled-components` plugin?

Comment: @juliomalves It might be, because as I stated above, when I transpile using babel with  `babel-plugin-styled-components` plugin it works fine. Only when I use webpack to compile the whole thing this issue arises. How would I go on to figuring out if the issue is indeed with using `babel-plugin-styled-components` with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Next natively has babel presets you should take advantage of. I use `"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.2"` in my `package.json` and this set up works for me with Webpack 5/Next 11.x in my `babel.config.json`:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [ 
      "styled-components", { 
        "ssr": true, 
        "displayName": true, 
        "preprocess": false 
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have my babel config set up the same as you in my next.js app and it is rendering the components, that are defined in my next.js app, as it should. Only the components that are imported from my external component library lack styles when next.js performs server side rendering.

Comment: The only component I see in your component library repo is called `Wrapper` and you're not exporting it.

Comment: The styled component is not exported, the react component is, which returns the styled component. Sorry if I made the question unclear to which component I am refering to. 
I have added a screenshot to the question, do you have a clue on what may be causing this?

Comment: I don't think you can serve the react component up from the app like this (you'd need to use the Next API: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction). If you're building a component library, there are tools that help with that specific task - you're making a lot of work for yourself going this route.

Comment: I don't quite understand how Next API would solve this issue, as far as I know the purpose of Next API is to handle api calls and database operations. Although I am far from an expert in Next so I am probably lacking some information here.
My actual project consists of multiple independent services which all use a lot of the same components, so to share common components between these services, a component library seems to me as the best way of achieving this.
When you say "tools" do you have any specific tools in mind?

Comment: It's a lot of work to build a component library that's external to your other app. I've built one before but it's complicated and will take you some time. This is a tutorial I found online that might get you started - https://blog.harveydelaney.com/creating-your-own-react-component-library/#component-library-overview.

Comment: `babel-styled-components` is now ported to Next.js https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#styled-components

You don't need an external `babel.config.json` anymore.

Comment: @DavidDias - if you're using Next `v12` and `swc` you don't even need babel anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the styles before the render to do that create file name `_document.js` under `pages/_document.js`. try this

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript, Html } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';
export default class MainDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang='en'>
        <Head>
          <link
            href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu'
            rel='stylesheet'
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <div id='modal-root' />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```